# How to populate child elements of ExpandableListView by calling Web-Service?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview

I have to create `ExpandableListView` of Authors list. When user expand any group or click on Group Item, than I have to call an web-service to populate all books(child) of that
author.
I have create an simple ExpandableListView in which I pass both GroupListItems and ChildListItem in adapter for populating `ExpandableListView`.
But now, I have to call web-service when user try to expand an GroupItem.

So here I am asking you, where I should call web-service for getting child data and how do I
notify it to adapter so that only child refresh not whole List.

Right now I am calling web-Service in `setOnGroupCollapseListener`, but not know how to notify child elements to adapter.
I cannot use `notifydatasetchanged` here because it refreshes my whole ListView.

Please Reply

Comment: what's the problem if your whole ListView is refreshed ?

Comment: As when user has selected an group item then, web-service is called to populate child data. On refreshing opened Group-Item will closed and user again has to open that Group-Item.

Comment: Then after you download and manipulate your particular group data , call notifydatasetchanged to refresh the list and expand the particular group programatically to avoid clicking again on that group.

Comment: thanks Ayon I will try this and notify you..